# Remove specific event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Attaching event handler:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(event){
  #1
});
```

This removes all `keypress` event handlers:

```
$(document).off('keypress');
```

I only want to remove  #1 from my code above

Can this be done without using namespaces? I don't want to create random strings to be used as namespaces :(

Comment: What's the problem with using namespaces? You don't need to use random strings. It would be preferable if you used meaningful strings for this. Then you don't have to lug around your original function in order to remove the event afterward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the original handler to `off`. Make sure you're passing the original and not a new anonymous function that just looks the same.

This means you'll need to store it.

```
var handler = function(event){
  #1
};

$(document).on('keypress', handler);
```

---

```
$(document).off('keypress', handler);
```

Comment: But the documentation says the 2nd argument is a selector string. 3rd one is a function, but of eventObject type. Mine is anonymous?!

Comment: @Elfy: Arguments in square brackets  denote optional arguments. That means any or all can be excluded. So in this case we exclude the string but include the function.

Comment: @Elfy The `Event eventObject` in the documentation is indicating what kind of parameter is passed to the function. There aren't multiple types of functions.